# powershell v2 copying to another domain

Tags: cross-domain, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to copy a file to a serrver in another domain, but since powershell v2 commandlets don't take credentials I tried using work-arounds.

I tried mapping the drive with new-psdrive

I tried net use

I even tried $webclient.fileupload

But I always get the CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError

Is there any way to maybe impersonate the domain?
Or another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Start your powershell as the different domain user and copy the files from local. Following link may help.

[Powershell running as a another user with elevated privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837130/powershell-running-as-a-another-user-with-elevated-privileges)

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I could come up with for this was to map the drive in the host machine to a drive letter, and enter the credentials then. Not very portable, but it was the only method that worked.