# Powershell connection to SQL server database in another domain using integrated security

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to write a powershell script to connect to a server in another domain using integrated security. This is the only way we can connect to our MS SQL server database due to a policy restriction. Right now I run it using SSMS by holding down shift and right clicking the SSMS shortcut, choosing run as a different user and put in my other domain credentials. Is there any equivalent option in powershell? I'm still using Powershell v 1.0 on a win7 64 bit vm. The sql server is ms sql 2k8 r2. Here is my code so far.

```
$dataSource = "ProdDomain"
$database = "MyProdDatabase"
$connectionString = "Server=$dataSource;Database=$database;Integrated Security=true;"
$query = "SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$result = $command.ExecuteReader()
$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($result)
$table | format-table
```

I get the following error:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."
>       At line:9 char:1
>       + $connection.Open()
>       + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>               + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>               + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Comment: You could run the PowerShell scripts as another user? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837130/powershell-running-as-a-another-user-with-elevated-privileges

Comment: Interesting idea Matt. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: You might also use the credential vault (cmdkey.exe) to specify a user/password to connect to the server.